# MST not picking up second monitor after restart

Tags: multiple-monitors, displayport, mst

I previously had two Dell U2415 monitors.   The devices where hooked up to the first monitor via a USB-C to DisplayPort cable and the first monitor was then connected to the second by a DisplayPort to mini-DisplayPort cable.   This was great and everything worked fine.

I have now replaced the first monitor with a Dell U2421e (primarily so I can replace the monitor, USB hub and power cables with a single USB-C connection).   The second monitor is still one of the U2415s connected via the same DisplayPort to mini-DisplayPort cable.

The issue is when I reboot a device the second monitor doesn't get recognised.  The first monitor always works and I get the same on multiple devices (Surface Book, Chromebook, HP laptop) so this suggests the issue is that the first monitor isn't recognising the second is chained to it.

Sometimes simply unplugging the USB-C cable from the device and reconnecting it works but others it takes several minutes of pulling cables, power cycling monitors and cursing for both displays to fire up.   Once they are on everything is fine, it is just that initial setup that is problematic.

Any suggesting on things to try to either make it work first time or at least something I can do that will consistently bring the second display to life as I can't work out a pattern to what does make it work.